# What is the use of this square bracket in the following code?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

```
vector < int > deg[1000]
```

What is the use of this square brackets?
If its for array of vectors, they why don't we use a 2D vector? its more efficient. found this in Lalit Kundu's code

Comment: why don't we use a 2D vector instead? its more efficient considering the space complexity.

Comment: @StoryTeller, please stress on your point

Comment: Blanket statements like *"it's more efficient"* are meaningless without the empirical data to back them. What's efficient for one problem may be completely wrong for another. Case and point: `std::list` can outperform `std::vector` by several factors in some multhithreaded programs, despite being "less efficient" lore-wise.

Comment: @story Teller, lets compare arrays and vectors out here.. in majority cases vectors help save memory compared to arrays. at worst case they both take up same memory.

Comment: And they also increase memory fragmentation and max working set size due to re-allocations, which may cause a memory allocation to fail sooner. This program may find it unacceptable. Like I said, blanket statements are not very useful.

Comment: @Story Teller, what about from a competitive programmers point of view?

Comment: Comments aren't really for extended discussion, but I'd imagine that it would depend on the purpose of the competition.

Comment: For usecases where a static amount of items is needed and the amount is small enough to fit into the target area (global, stack, ... where is this placed?), using an array can be completely reasonable. However, 1000 times the size of a vector object wouldn't be within my definition of "reasonable" to be placed in the stack (not even talking about putting *anything* into global)

Comment: @NeelAlex huh? vectors take up more memory than arrays of the same size in all cases.

Comment: @NeelAlex Don't just compare `sizeof(std::vector<int>)` and `sizeof(int[N])`. `vector` allocates its buffer externally, so its memory cost is `sizeof(int[vector.size()]) + sizeof(vector<int>)`

Answer (score 1):

> What is the use of this square brackets?

It declares `deg` to be an array of 1000 elements of type `vector<int>`. There should be a semicolon at the end to make that statement complete.

> If its for array of vectors, they why don't we use a 2D vector?

Probably because the top level array size does not change.